# Visual Studio Code unable to activate virtual environment automatically in commandPrompt , but works with 'base conda environment'

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda, conda

CHECK THIS GIF....
[The GIF I recorded with problem.](https://i.loli.net/2019/07/24/5d3877e5e155093689.gif)

I used anaconda-navigator and created a new virtual environment. Visual studio code detected this environment, and I can debug with that env. However it will not automatically activate that env in the built-in command prompt.

[The screen shot of what's happend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PItos.png)

But if I selected 'Anaconda3':conda in VSCode, the visual studio does use

```
C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/Scripts/activate.bat
```

help me to get into the base env

[The screen shot of successful activated with base env](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dg4Fz.png)

I tried to use anaconda navigator to create a new env, but it's also not working. It can only be detected by VSCode, but will not activate it for me.

Whats happening here?

Answer (score 0):

that is because the conda did not provide the file "activate.ps1" for powershell,but just "activate.bat" for cmd.so you should change the default shell(terminal) to cmd, and then the conda env will be activated

Comment: Like I said I have used cmd in visual studio code. And also, the base env works fine with auto activate. I have no idea.

Comment: when you add a new shell, VSCode will run "conda activate envname",so what it say?

Comment: 所以就是说，你不是可以在左下角选择不同的Python环境嘛。然后我选择Anaconda3:conda，然后ctrl + ` 然后cmd就打开了，也自动帮我激活

Comment: 但是 如果我用anaconda新建了一个环境，也装了基本的包，Visual Studio Code 也能检测到，但是CMD不会帮我Activate，我需要自己Activate，很奇怪

Comment: what do you mean? I've selected anohter conda env

Comment: did your base env had a prompt "base"?

Comment: I don't konw why,but my Anaconda is diffrent with you.Such as the path of new conda env and the name of base env

Comment: It used to work. But after I uninstall and reinstall l the anaconda due to some problems with anaconda navigator, it’s not working anymore.

Answer (score 0):

After I uninstall & reinstall the anaconda 3, everything works just fine. It might be just a bug of anaconda or VS